# PDF file generated by Prawn throws "Failed - server error" when I try to download it from the browser's pdf viewer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a PDF file that is generated in ruby on rails with Prawn.
I used send_file with `disposition: inline`.

```
pdf = <A method is called to generate the PDF>

pdf.render_file file_path   # file_path = public/assets/reports/test_report.pdf

send_file(file_path, filename: 'test_report.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline')
```

The pdf is displayed as expected but when I try to download it from the browser's pdf viewer after the pdf is displayed, it throws me an error saying "failed - server error".

[Download button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBwrw.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx6IP.png)

Has anyone faced this issue or have a possible solution to it?

Tried using `send_data` instead of `send_file` the issue still remains. I have tried searching through the internet including stack overflow, didn't find a proper solution. I went through PrawnRails documentation, no luck there too.